# Getting mysql_affected_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given - Yet query inserts into database succesfully - What gives?

Tags: php, mysql

This problem has me stumped.  I get this error even though the when I check the database in phpmyadmin the query successfully inserts into the database.  So I know the query goes through and is not false.  What I'm trying to do is register a user, and if there is a result returned - return that to be checked true or false i.e. if result exist then continue.  The code in my class;

```
class registerUser {

    function register($email,$password) {
        $query = "insert into users(email,password) values('".$email."','".$password."')";
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Could not enter the user into the database".mysql_error());

        return mysql_affected_rows($result); 
    }

    function checkPasswords($password1,$password2) {
        if($password1 == $password2) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The file that uses the class:

```
include('../data/connection.php');
include('../data/registerUser.php');

$connect = new connection();
$connect->connect($con, $db);
$register = new registerUser();
$checkPass = $register->checkPasswords($_POST['regpass'],$_POST['confirm']);

if($checkPass) {
    $reg = $register->register($_POST['regemail'],$_POST['regpass']);
        if($reg) {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['id'] = $_POST['email'];
            $connect->close($con);
            header("Location:dashboard.php");    
        } else  {
           // Failure - message
            echo "Registration not successful, contact Administrator";
        }   
} else {
    echo "Passwords do not match";    
}
```

It seems like it never gets past the register function in registerUser and executes the die message in the mysql_query, yet the insert is successful when checked in phpMyAdmin.  What am I doing wrong?  Any help much appreciated!!

Comment: I do procedural PHP, but doesn't your function need to have `$connect` inside it? Have you tried adding `global $connect` insider your query?

Comment: I don't think so, it connects to the database just fine.  The problem is when the query executes.  But the query actually does execute, even though I still get that error message.

Answer (score 3):

```
return mysql_affected_rows($result);
```

To fix it, remove the parameter `$result`:

```
return mysql_affected_rows();
```

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things from http://php.net/mysql_query

1. mysql is "discouraged", suggested alternative are mysqli or PDO.
2. mysql_query on insert returns a boolean

And from http://php.net/mysql_affected_rows

The resource it is expecting is the DB link, not the query results.  If you only have one connection to the database, the parameter is optional.

Additionally, you may want to add input escaping to deal with sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass the connection variable like mysqli_affected_rows($conn);    here $conn is my connection variable